# wpf: Mousedoubleclick for textbox

Tags: wpf, mouseevent

How to handle mousedoubleclick in textbox text in xaml.

This is how i am doing it for enter keyboard enter in xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FullName, Mode=OneWay}" 
         IsReadOnly="True"
         x:Name="txtFullName"/>
<Button Command="{Binding OpenStaffDialogCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtFullName}" 
        Width="0" 
        IsDefault="{Binding IsFocused, ElementName=txtFullName}" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle the [MouseDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx) event.

Comment: Like i did for keyboard enter. Something similar but with no code behind.